# How to access the Maya main menu and toolbar?

Tags: python, qt, menu, toolbar, maya

I use Autodesk Maya 2016 + Python.

I had a problem. I need to replace the functions of standard menu items and toolbars. For example, you must add the function to save a recording function. And because different people use different functionality, you have to change everything at once. Someone presses `Ctrl+S`, others go to the menu `File->Save`, and some press icon on the toolbar. In all areas it is necessary to replace the functionality. I understand that the problem boils down to in order to access the menus, toolbars and keyboard shortcuts. Next, find the associates item on the estate to know what function is now called. Then replace it with their cause and at the end of the function that invoked earlier in this menu.

1. how to get Maya main menu (like `File` and other)?
2. how to get Maya main toolbar?
3. how to get Maya hotkeys?

Maya is based on QT. So just need to get the objects, and then have the standard means of QT can do everything.

How to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure, do you want to override completely the save function and replace it with your own? Or do you want to call some of your code and then call the old save function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three ways of doing this call the `runTimeCommand` named `SaveScene`. Override that command and you have hijacked all of the three ways you describe. This is a bit tricky since the command is marked with the flag `-default` which makes it impossible to change them on the fly. You can hook them where they are first defined. They are defined in the file:

- Mayadir/scripts/startup/defaultRunTimeCommands.mel

Copy this file to your user profile maya script directory or studio script directry. These will get precedence of factory script due to resolution order. **Do not** overwrite the factory file. Then change `-command` in the lines,

```
runTimeCommand -default true
    -annotation (uiRes("m_defaultRunTimeCommands.kSaveSceneAnnot"))
    -category   ("File")
    -command    ("checkForUnknownNodes(); FileMenu_SaveItem")
    SaveScene;
```

to something else. Best would be just to add a hook here.

Obviously, you can also change the button/menuitem and hotkey too. So what you do is run following mel (it's easier to do this in mel since the bulk of the commands are built that way, port to python or c++ if you must):

```
runTimeCommand
    -annotation "Print the word \"Hello\""
    -command ("print \"foo\"")
    MySave;
nameCommand         
    -annotation "Print the word \"Hello\""
    -command ("print \"foo\"")
    MySaveNamed;
buildFileMenu();
menuItem -e -c "MySave" "MayaWindow|mainFileMenu|saveItem";
iconTextButton -e -c "MySave2" openSceneButton;
hotkey -keyShortcut "s" -ctl -name ("MySaveNamed");
```

**Warning:** The hotkey will be permanent in prefs, until you change it back or reset prefs.

*Please note*: There are at least two other ways user could save and you could not have full control of those even if you wanted to.

Comment: I was able to intercept all activity except one. I can not understand what triggered when the user selects a file in Recent Files? How to connect a function to process Recent Files?

Comment: @MaxKu press control and shift down while choosing to open a recent file, this makes a shortcut for that menu item in shelf. Then you see that it calls a function `openRecentFile` Now override that. Like i said there is no real way to be perfectly safe. (By the way the reason i can easily see these is because i have made a introspection tool that shows **any** GUI item when i hold shift control alt and right click on it, i suggest you build one too it saves a lot of time)

Comment: and one more question ) i change open atcion to myOpen. but its worked inside maya when i start maya and open file. but when i doubleClick to file.mb in windows - its open in maya used standart maya function not my... how to find this function and change to myOpen?

Comment: @MaxKu change what your double click does. Like i said this is a rabbit hole you will never win. There is NO guarantee that all cases will be filled. I an always circumvent you.

Comment: I found another way. I have a pulse function to track mouse movement in Maya. I used it to check for open file...

Comment: @MaxKu why did you not load your stuff in users setup or the default file?

Answer (score 0):

seeing the original answer was from 2016 and maya has lots of python support added since then, here is something for more recent versions.

> 1. how to get Maya main menu (like File and other)?

You can search for a menu from the main menu toolbar with this code

```py
import maya

def find_menu(name):
    # get the main window
    gMainWindow = maya.mel.eval('$temp=$gMainWindow')

    # get all the menus that are children of the main menu
    mainWindowMenus = maya.cmds.window(gMainWindow, query=True, menuArray=True)
    for menu in mainWindowMenus:
        print(menu)
        if menu.lower() == name.lower():
            return menu
```

you can then make a new menu entry under this with

```py
pm.menuItem(optional_unique_name,label="click me", command="print('hi')", parent= the_name_you_got_returned)
```